# Cannot play (or rip) Audio CD (but DVD and Data play)

Tags: sound, mount, vlc, cd

Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)
I cannot play (or rip) Audio CDs.  I can play and read DVDs and data CDs / DVDs.  When I try to play an audio CD in VLC I get the following error:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'cdda:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.
```

This is the output from cd-info:

```
$ cd-info --no-cddb /dev/cdrom
cd-info version 0.83 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2011 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
CD location   : /dev/cdrom
CD driver name: GNU/Linux
   access mode: IOCTL

Vendor                      : ATAPI   
Model                       : iHAS124   B     
Revision                    : AL0H
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : Yes
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
__________________________________

Disc mode is listed as: Error in getting information
++ WARN: error in ioctl CDROMREADTOCHDR: No medium found

cd-info: Can't get first track number. I give up.
```

I have searched a lot of similar sounding problem reports on the internet but found no solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally the audio CDs that I was trying to play are non-standard audio CDs and probably cannot be read by my combination of DVD-ROM and Linux software.

Specifically these CDs are "Filippa Giordano" and "il rosso amore" both published by Warner Music Europe.  Eventually by chance I loaded "Con Amor a Mexico" published by Sony Music and to my astonishment it loaded and played automatically!

The murky background to this problem is explained on the following Wikipeda page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_Control.